# Docker export the version of an installed package

Tags: docker, dockerfile, github-actions

I am trying to build a docker image using a Dockerfile via GitHub actions. Github action job has the below step:

```
  - name: Build image
    id: build-image
    env:
      SOME_TAG: nginx.v${{ github.run_number}}
    run: |
      docker build -t SOME_TAG -f ./nginx/Dockerfile .
      docker push SOME_TAG
```

Above step runs a dockerfile then pushes the image to a repository

Part of the Dockerfile, I am installing nginx using a simple apt:

`RUN apt -y install nginx`

Then I am running below step to see the version of the nginx installed in the GitHub actions output logs:

`RUN nginx -v`

However, now I realised it is better if I tag the image with the version of nginx installed. To be able to achieve this, the docker image needs to spit out some information somehow. I will need to export the info from the build step.

This is where I got stuck, is there a way to get the installed version information out of the docker build step?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Dockerfile you could build the image, run `nginx -v` to get the version and **then** tag and push your image.

```
  - name: Build image
    id: build-image
    run: |
      docker build -t temp_tag -f ./nginx/Dockerfile .
      MYTAG=$(docker run --rm -it temp_tag sh -c "nginx -v" | awk -F/ '{print $2}' | tr -d '\r')
      docker tag temp_tag $MYTAG
      docker push $MYTAG
```